# Sectioning Fetched Results Controller breaks Search Display

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm absolutely bamboozled by this and can't work out what am I missing. Perhaps a lot still to learn about core data.

This is my Fetched Results Controller which displays a section-less table but my search display controller works:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.buckyballDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

WHEREAS as soon as I apply a *sectionNameKeyPath*, to add sections. Sections get added but my search display controller is broken, throwing the below error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableViewRowData.m:1630
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath 0x7481040> 2 indexes [0, 1])'
```

**And here are my Table view data source implementations** Where *filteredList* is an NSArray:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.filteredList count];
    }
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        if (index > 0)
        {
            return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index-1];
        }
        else
        {
            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
            return NSNotFound;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        NSMutableArray *index = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
        NSArray *initials = [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
        [index addObjectsFromArray:initials];
        return index;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Exception is thrown in *cellForRowAtIndexPath* at the below line:-

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Please do ask if need to provide more information.. I'm scratching my head so much on this one..

Comment: Try using `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and not `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thanks for that @chris ... it got the search display controller working. BUT any updates (couple of deletions) in the core data breaks the table such that all data disappears except indexes and sections names. The thing works without sectioning and indexing :-(. ERROR was: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil with userInfo (null)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077332/how-to-refresh-a-uitableviewcontroller-or-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: @chris Please move your comments into an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Answerbot Done.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and not `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:.`

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714737/where-does-the-indexpath-of-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath-get